# Create Chart using $getJSON and ChartJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, chart.js

I need to create a chart using ChartJS and a JSON file. The format is give below and I wish to push the data into an array, where the x-Axis has the Station labeled, and the y-Axis shows the Arrivals. So essentially I am creating a bar chart with the Arrivals in Seconds for a Station. I understand how to render a chart, my problem is pushing the data into an array for the chart.

```
[
{"group":"23","delays":[
{"Station":"a","Arrival":"3","Departure":0},{"Station":"b","Arrival":-179,"Departure":0},{"Station":"c","Arrival":-156,"Departure":0}
]},
{"group":"23","delays":[
{"Station":"d","Arrival":"no information","Departure":79},{"Station":"f","Arrival":0,"Departure":0},{"Station":"g","Arrival":68,"Departure":68}
]}
]
```

The Json exerpt is above and below the Loop that I try to use to push it however I get an undefined error.

```
var dataPoints = [];


function addData(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            dataPoints.push({
                x: data[i].delays[j].Station,
                y: data[i].delays[j].Arrival
            });
        }
    }

    console.log(dataPoints)
    chart.render();

}

$.getJSON(url, addData);
```

This is the error:

```
test.html:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Station' of undefined
    at Object.addData [as success] (test.html:33)
    at j (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
```

Comment: `dataPoints` is never defined

Comment: @johnSmith what do you mean by that? i have defined it above as an empty array?

Comment: nevermind, that was before your code-formatting-edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a problem is that you are not iterating `j` according to the length of delays but to the length of data, should be working if u adjust it sth. like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].delays.length; j++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much! it works, the array is filled. however the chart wont show any columns but i have got to figure that out in some way.